# how to get elements inside <form> tag of web page?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to access a button which is present inside "form" tag of website, if i print the inner text of form i can able to get the entire page but i don't know how to access the elements inside the form.

Code tried:

```
Dim workFrame As HTMLFormElement, test As HTMLFormElement
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Set workFrame = ie2.Document.forms("ViewReferral")
Debug.Print workFrame.innerText ' it will print the whole page
Debug.Print workFrame.elements("notsuccess").innerText ' this triggered an error
```

Web Page

```
<form name="ViewReferral" action="viewreferral.php" method="POST">
<input name="Id" id="Id" type="hidden" value="11111">
<input name="Message" id="Message" type="hidden" value="">
 <div id="data-form" style="padding: 10px;">

    <div style="padding: 10px; float: left;"><h1>View Referral (Id = 11111)</h1></div>

        <div class="order">
            <a class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"role="button" style="float: right; display: inline;" href="managedocuments.php">Back</a>
            <a class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button" style="float: right; display: inline;" href="vieworder.pdf.php?OrderId=111111" target="_blank">Print</a>
                <a class="VoidOrder ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button" style="float: right; display: inline;" href="#1111"> Void</a>
                        <a class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button" style="float: right; display: inline;" href="markasprocessed.php?OrderId=11111">Mark as Processed</a>
```

Here i would like to activate href="vieworder.pdf.php?
I am unable to access the tables inside the web form, please help me to fix this issue.
Thank You.

Comment: This may guide you a little bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000306/how-to-get-web-elements-using-vba?rq=1

Comment: try using `workFrame.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget") (1)` and `.Click` or `.innerText` or whatever method you wish to use with the <a> tag.

Comment: Call `ie2.Document.querySelector("a[href*='markasprocessed.php']")` to get the button.

Comment: @Nicholas Kemp thank you so much it worked fine, you saved me ...keep helping..

Answer (score 1):

Formalizing my comment, what you should try is using `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an array of every element in the document or form with a given class. In your case, since the `<a>` tag you want to work with is the second tag with the class `"ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"`, and is in the `workFrame` form, the code line that should work for you is:

```
workFrame.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget") (1)
```

where the (1) tells the program to return the second item in the array (arrays start indexing from 0).

Comment: thank you, one small doubt how should i assign an object for those element? I used Dim test As object and set test = workFrame.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget") (1), it throws me an error also i tried using Dim test As test As HTMLFormElement still it throws an error

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but what is exactly what you want to accomplish with that? Maybe there's another way.

Answer (score 1):

A nice CSS selector was given in the comments with

```
.Document.querySelector("a[href*='markasprocessed.php']")
```

The `*` means containing. So the `a` tag that has an `href` containing the literal string `'markasprocessed.php`

---

Or

```
.Document.querySelector("a[href^='markasprocessed.php']")
```

The `^` means starts with. So the `a` tag that has an `href` starting with the literal string `'markasprocessed.php`

[image: css query 1]

---

You could also use a less robust positional based selector with:

```
.Document.querySelector("a[href]:nth-child(4)")
```

[image: CSS selector]

The 4th `a` tag containing an `href.`