# Crawler & Scraping

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to access an intranet website, then select from a dropdown menu, then pass a value in a text field, thing is the code is debuging where the Dropdown menu needs to be selected, and its not selecting any option from the dropdown menu.

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("Home URL")
    Do
        If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
            IE.Visible = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop

    IE.Document.forms(0).all("txtUsername").Value = ""
    IE.Document.forms(0).all("txtPassword").Value = ""
    IE.Document.forms(0).submit

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

   IE.Navigate ("Search URL")

Do

Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

Dim z As Object

Set z = IE.Document.getElementById("cboFieldName").selectedIndex = 6

 DoEvents

    ie.Document.getElementById("txtFieldValue").Select
    SendKeys (cell.Value)

    DoEvents

    ie.Document.getElementById("cmdFind").Click

Next cell

End Sub
```

and the below from the website

```
<form action="search.asp?Find=1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <br><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><b><font size="3" face="cambria" color="#e60000">Please enter your search criteria:</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <select name="cboFieldName">
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            <option value="1">Customer Name</option>
                            <option value="2">Customer Reference</option>
                            <option value="3">Site Name</option>
                            <option value="4">Site City</option>
                            <option value="5">Site Country</option>
                            <option value="6">Global Service Reference</option>
                            <option value="7">Customer Service Reference</option>
```

Comment: Personally I find solving these difficult without a URL to work with. Is the URL an internal site (think I saw another of your questions) ?

Comment: @QHarr It isn't just you. Without a url these questions are not a [mcve] and in many cases deserve to be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In web page to select a value from drop down there are many ways, it totally depends on how the web page has been build. Try the below code to select from drop down

Code1:

```
IE.Document.all("cboFieldName").selectedIndex = 6
IE.Document.all("cboFieldName").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

for some drop down you can directly pass a value

Code 2:

```
Set z = IE.Document.all("cboFieldName")
z.Value = "Global Service Reference" ' update the option name
```

Updated:

```
Dim workForm As HTMLFormElement
Set workForm = ie2.Document.forms("form name") 'update your exact form name
workForm.all("cboFieldName").selectedIndex = 6
workForm.all("cboFieldName").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

to help you better, please provide the code in website associated with the drop down button.

Thank You

Comment: Thank  you Arun, please check the below

Comment: you can try the updated one in my answer if it not works then  please locate if the drop down button is present inside your form element or not? if the drop down button is a part of your form element then, you have to use form object to activate element inside form

Comment: for form element you can view  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137730/how-to-get-elements-inside-form-tag-of-web-page)

Comment: Hi Arun, I've tried to use the two codes, and its still not working :( 

and I've checked the referrence and I don't how can I relate this to my code :(

Comment: @HanyAbdElRahman try the updated one else you can post the url of your website by that every one can help to solve your issue.

Comment: I've tried both, and I did attach the Web HTML code above (below the vba code) if it will help, as it gives the same info you'd get it from url :(